# Multi Parameter Search in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I need Multi-Parameter search for custom post type in WordPress.
I have 4 option to search.
1- Custom post type Category.
1- Custom post type Services
3- Location1
4- Location2

Check the screenshot for more details -  https://prnt.sc/n3kr6d

I am using this query.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type'             => 'directory_listing',
'posts_per_page'        => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(

        'taxonomy' => 'listing_country',
        'field'    => 'listing_country',
        'terms'    => $locationstring1,
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'listing_categories',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $category_list,
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'services_offered',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $services_offered,
    ),
    ),

));
```

Comment: Are you passing anything in form ?

Comment: Yes All value pass by forms

Comment: Add your full code here

Comment: You do not need to pas two loop i guess, Add up your full code so  can check and help you out.

Comment: at that time I am trying many code  if you have any suggestion or code so please provide, i will try any update you.

Comment: You are passing category right ? If not than we need to pass tax_query along with given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your file and let me know the result.

First, you need to pass your form data.

```
$post_type = $_REQUEST['form_field_name'];
$cat_id = $_REQUEST['form_field_name'];
```

Then add this in your query parameter

```
<?php
$args     = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category_name_here',
    'terms' => $cat_id,
    'field' => 'id',        
    ),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $wp_query->have_posts()):
    while ( $wp_query ->have_posts()):
        the_post();
        echo the_title();
        echo the_content();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else:
    echo wpautop('Sorry, no posts were found');
endif;
?>
```

Comment: No result found

Comment: Edited code also do let me know you want to pass only one category at time right ?

Comment: Yes I am passing only one category value, same result.

Comment: 'taxonomy' => 'category_name_here',

Did you change this to your cat name ?

Comment: You can find your cat name from url too for ex. http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product

Comment: Than your cat name will be product_cat

Comment: Its show all listing title, not for any single category